# Isomorphism between group cohomology groups

Tags: homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

Consider a profinite group $S$ acting trivially on $\mathbb{F}_p$.
Choose $\chi \neq 0\in H^1(S, \mathbb{F}_p)$ and set $T = \ker(\chi)$.
Let $X$ be the $S$-Module of all functions $S/T \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_p$.

Show that there exists a canonical isomorphism
$$
H^q(S,X) \cong H^q(T,\mathbb{F}_p).
$$

The case $q=0$ is obvious, since $X^S$ consists of the constant functions and $\mathbb{F}_p^T = \mathbb{F}_p$ may be embedded into $X$ as the constant functions.

But how do I proceed from there? Dimension shifting doesn't seem to work here or am I missing something?

Comment: You don't need to write \text{ker}; you can just write \ker.  That automatically provides proper spacing before an after "ker" in expressions like $5\ker f$.  (I editing the question accordingly.)

Comment: Thanks. I did wonder if this is supported, but didn't try it

Comment: That looks like Shapiro's Lemma

Comment: Yes it does. Thank you for the hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to i. m. soloveichik I was able to solve my question.

There exists an isomorphism

$$
\text{Ind}^T_S(\mathbb{F}_p) \cong \text{Map}(S/T, \mathbb{F}_p) = X
$$
given by
$$
x(\sigma) \mapsto y(\sigma T) = \sigma x (\sigma^{-1})
$$

By [Shapiro's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapiro%27s_lemma#Statement_for_group_cohomology) we get the isomorphism

$$
H^q(S, \: \text{Ind}^T_S(\mathbb{F}_p)) \cong H^q(T,\mathbb{F}_p).
$$

A proof is found in  Neukirch/Schmidt/Wingberg: 'Cohomology of Number Fields' p. 60.